# How to hide the App icon/launcher icon middle of splash screen

Tags: android

My theme looks like this:

```
 <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBarLaunch" parent="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
     <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splashscreen</item>
     <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
</style>
```

Note: I am on API level 31.

Everytime I launch the app, the splash screen displays the app icon or launcher icon in the middle of the splash screen. I want to hide it, is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: add the android version?

Comment: android Api level 31

Comment: It would be helpful you could provide screenshots showing what you want

Comment: @Dinux i just want to hide the laucher icon which is automatically add to the center of splash screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide the app icon or launcher icon in the splash screen, you have to customise the splash screen. You can replace the default icon with a transparent image. To do so, you have to add the following code in the `themes.xml` file:

```
<item name="android:windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/my_icon</item>
```

where `my_icon` is a transparent image file.

Complete code:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.MyApplication" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        ...
        <item name="android:windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/my_icon</item>
        ...
    </style>
</resources>
```

Result:

[image]

For more info: [Docs](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen)

Answer (score 1):

To hide the app icon in the middle of the splash screen, set the windowActionBar attribute to false in the AppTheme.NoActionBarLaunch style.

Comment: It doesn't work